# HTTP wrapper methods in Swift as a function call - handling Asynchronous behavior

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to write some HTTP get request methods in Swift as a function call. The goal is to abstract these (HTTP API calls) so that consumer methods (front end ones) can call them and if the call succeeds, return something. My design is like this (the below code is not 100% accurate, but it conveys what I intend to achieve).

```
class HTTPAPI {

    func getListings(id: String) -> Int { 
        print("Get listings for id \(id)")
        let url = NSURL(string: ("http://localhost" + id))
        print("Fetching URL \(url)....")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
            if error == nil {
                return 200
            }
            else {
                return 400
            }
    }
}
```

Given the asynchronous nature of these HTTP calls, should I write these helper functions themselves as completion blocks and have the NSURLConnection calls within those completion blocks.

In a general purpose programming language like python it's easier to abstract these, but the asynchronous nature of Swift slightly complicates things. I want the right way to make getListings reusable from any other consumer classes (say a ViewController).